# Deadbolt door trim guard?

Tags: doors, trim, deadbolt

So I have an outside door w/ a deadbolt. Someone left the deadbolt extended but the door open and went to shut it and as a result the deadbolt dented the heck out of my interior door trim (inswing door).

What is the name of a "plate" that I'd install on the inside trim to protect from deadbolt strikes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a door edge guard? These door edge guards are constructed of solid brass and come in a variety of different  finishes. These door edge guards are used to protect the door trim from being dented or damaged by swing bar type locking hardware. They feature an adhesive backing that provides for a quick and easy install, together with the assurance of a strong and permanent hold. These types of edge guards are designed for use in both residential and commercial applications.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re looking for a door latch guard. Scroll through here:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B07N2ZK65K/ref=sspa_mw_detail_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N2ZK65K)

It could also be a latch protector:

https://latchprotector.com/products/1-5-x-10-latch-protector-narrow-zinc-lp230-latch-guard?variant=24021644279872&currency=USD&utm_campaign=gs-2019-01-24&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign

If not, I’d try Emtek.com. They have a terrible website, but great customer service. Describe your problem and they’ll find the solution.

Comment: I pruned the shopping advice from the question since that's off topic. It would be helpful to see this answer updated to describe the parts rather than product links (or include photos). Thanks!